# How do I import another script in Python?

Tags: python

I'm creating a simple text-based adventure game. I have a long piece of code for combat, but I don't want to copy+paste it every time there's a fight. Is there a way for me to put the combat code into another script, and simply run that whenever combat occurs?

Comment: writing a function can be one way to do that.

Comment: Your answer is in the title of your question...

Comment: `import myscript`

Comment: To be clear: [import](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html?highlight=import)

Answer (score 1):

Put that code in a function and save it in another file, in the same directory.

Then in the file where you want to use your function, import the file at the top like:

```
import newFile
```

where newFile.py is the name of your file. You do not need .py here. And when you want to use a function from the imported file, use :

```
newFile.newFunction()
```

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a pythonsource use the `runpy`-module:

```
import runpy
runpy.run_module(
    mod_name     = "combat.py",
    init_globals = None,
    run_name     = "__main__",
    alter_sys    = None
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to do exactly that. First you will put at the top of your code `import theScript` then your code in that script should be a specific method called possibly doCombat, so you will call `theScript.doCombat()` in your piece of code.

A great tip that I learned in a computer science class is that if you are ever about to copy and paste code, 90% of the time it should be contained in a method which you should call.